# Regarding importing JPEG image

Tags: gis, netlogo

I have a scaned JPEG image of a location with path ways,building and play grounds but without any digitized data. It is a simple drawing on paper as a thought process of an area. So, I want to import this image as a environment and to move agents on it according to pacth colors. Like if road gray color, if gorund green color, if water blue color and so on.

I have gone through the dictionary, and available web links but still unable to do. I imported the image but finding difficult with patches. I tried to convert it into vector format which is .svg and then to .png to import but the patch coordinate value and patch color when i inspect are confusing.

Now i am trying to digitize it using a GIS software QGIS, to make it ascii. Let's see. Please help me out where i am lacking.

[image]
I am sorry for the vagueness of my question. Above is the image, i created in paint. I am able to import the image with 
                           import-drawing "map.png" 
                           import-pcolors "map.png"
but i am unable to ask agents to move only on the patches with pcolor = gray (assumed as road of the map). with the below code i asked to stay on the area with green color.

```
to setup
 clear-all

 import-drawing "map.png"
 import-pcolors "map.png"

 create-turtles 5[
        set xcor -21
        set ycor -2
        set color red
        set shape "person"
        set size 0.5
  ]
end

to go
   ask turtles [ fd 1 if pcolor != 64.3 [ set heading heading - 180]]
end
```

Hope now i am able to make understand.

Comment: Thanks for improving your question. I modified your code so the turtles start in a gray area, and I changed `64.3` to `7.4`, and it worked fine — the turtles stayed on the road, as expected. Are you experiencing something different? Here's an image of a run with 100 turtles with their pens down: http://cl.ly/image/2N0p342m1B0j/road.png

Answer (score 1):

Use the primitive import-pcolors it can accept most picture formats.

Here is a scheme that I have found useful
if my drawing is clearly and evenly colored I use import-pcolors it takes BMP, JPG, GIF, and PNG. You can also do it from the Menu File

if it is not I use import-pcolors-rgb and use code that looks a bit like this to tease out the regions I want.

```
ask patches
  [
  if item 0 pcolor > RA and item 1 pcolor < RB and item 2 pcolor < RC 
     [set pcolor rgb 255 0 0]
       .
       .
       .
  ]
```

then I make RA RB RC etc etc sliders and tweak them until I have the regions I want.

The easiest of course is to use distinct solid colors.

Ask one of the grey patches what color it is use that number instead of 64.3